# How to re-shape pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a following df:

```
  id   points
0 1    (2,3)
1 1    (2,4)
2 1    (4,6)
3 5    (6,7)
4 5    (8,9)
```

I am trying to obtain the following data frame:

```
  id    points
0 1     (2,3), (2,4), (4,6)
1 5     (6,7), (8,9)
```

Please suggest me to obtain the expected data frame.

Comment: Are `points` actually `tuple` or `str`?

Comment: A `Dataframe` strikes me like the wrong data structure. Already having tuples as elements is a red flag, but the you want to aggregate into a tuple of tuples... Why not just a `dict`?

Comment: I got the points column after zipping two separate columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `points` are `tuple`

```
df.groupby('id').points.apply(list).reset_index()

   id                    points
0   1  [(2, 3), (2, 4), (4, 6)]
1   5          [(6, 7), (8, 9)]
```

If you want an `array`

```
df.groupby('id').points.apply(lambda x: np.array(x.values.tolist())).reset_index()

   id                    points
0   1  [[2, 3], [2, 4], [4, 6]]
1   5          [[6, 7], [8, 9]]
```

If `points` are `str`

```
df.groupby('id').points.apply(', '.join).reset_index()

   id               points
0   1  (2,3), (2,4), (4,6)
1   5         (6,7), (8,9)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the first method for tuples worked. Also, is there a way I could get a list of array instead of list of tuples in each row like- [ [2,3], [2,4], [4,6] ]